# Yotubr_dl ошибка URL <urlopen error unknown url type: c> (caused by URLError('unknown url type: c'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, youtube-dl

Делаю программу на PyQt5 и Yotube_dl для скачивания видео. Ориентируюсь на код с ютуба.
Вот:

```
import youtube_dl
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 500))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1200, 1000))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../../../../Downloads/youtube.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(62, 62, 62);\n"
"background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);")
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.url_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.url_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 500, 30))
        self.url_line.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.url_line.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.url_line.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"border: 1px solid red;")
        self.url_line.setText("")
        self.url_line.setReadOnly(False)
        self.url_line.setCursorMoveStyle(QtCore.Qt.LogicalMoveStyle)
        self.url_line.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.url_line.setObjectName("url_line")
        self.path_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.path_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 425, 30))
        self.path_line.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"border: 1px solid red;")
        self.path_line.setText("")
        self.path_line.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.path_line.setObjectName("path_line")
        self.quality_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.quality_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 111, 25))
        self.quality_label.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.quality_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.quality_label.setObjectName("quality_label")
        self.quality_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.quality_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 130, 251, 23))
        self.quality_box.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 10pt \"Times New Roman\";")
        self.quality_box.setEditable(False)
        self.quality_box.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.AdjustToContents)
        self.quality_box.setObjectName("quality_box")
        self.quality_box.addItem("")
        self.download_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.download_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 350, 150, 28))
        self.download_but.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"Times New Roman\";\n"
"color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.download_but.setObjectName("download_but")
        self.path_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.path_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 80, 60, 30))
        self.path_but.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../../рабочий стол обои/Find.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.path_but.setIcon(icon1)
        self.path_but.setObjectName("path_but")
        self.info_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.info_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 460, 600, 20))
        self.info_label.setStyleSheet("font: 75 12pt \"Times New Roman\";")
        self.info_label.setText("")
        self.info_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.info_label.setObjectName("info_label")
        self.download = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 400, 550, 25))
        self.download.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 10pt \"Times New Roman\";")
        self.download.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.download.setObjectName("download")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Youtube downloader"))
        self.url_line.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вставьте URL ссылку на видео"))
        self.path_line.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите папку для видео"))
        self.quality_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Качество видео"))
        self.quality_box.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Только аудио"))
        self.download_but.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скачать"))
        self.path_but.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Путь"))
        self.download_but.clicked.connect(self.download_video)
        self.path_but.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.url_flag = False
        self.fol_flag = False
        self.setupUi(self)


    def get_video(self):
        if len(self.url_line.text()) > 5:
            self.url = self.url_line.text()
            self.url_flag = True


    def download_video(self):
        self.get_video()
        if self.url_flag:
            if self.fol_flag:
                self.run()
            else:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Вы не указали папку')
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', "Вы не указали URL ссылку!")




    def get_folder(self):
        self.dow_fol = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку для видео")
        if self.dow_fol != '':
            self.fol_flag = True
            self.path_line.setText(str(self.dow_fol))
            os.chdir(self.dow_fol)


    def locker(self, lock_val):
        buttons = [self.path_but, self.download_but]
        for i in buttons:
            i.setDisabled(lock_val)

    def run(self):
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}) as ydl:
            ydl.download([self.dow_fol])
            self.locker(True)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Так вот. Когда нажимаю кнопку скачать выдает ошибку

**[generic] Desktop: Requesting header
[generic] Desktop: Downloading webpage
WARNING: Could not send HEAD request to C:/Users/Mr.White/Desktop: 
ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError('unknown url type: c'))**

Comment: `ydl.download([self.dow_fol])` - так, ну это папка куда качать `self.dow_fol`, а что качать то, какой `URL` с видео, где указано? Может туда `self.url` надо передать?

Comment: как тогда передать путь скачивания?

Comment: Ну попробуйте так: `ydl.download([self.url])`, судя по другим вопросам тут про `ydl.download` нужно так делать.